# Created a tab but wont function on click - jQuery issue/newbie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

My website builder has a generic tab function but I don't like it, so I thought I would learn how to build one myself. I'm more comfortable with CSS than scripts at the moments and it shows with what I created, where it looks how I want but is not yet functional on clicks.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6oq3t9ev/1/

```
<ul class="tab_conts" id="recent" style="display: block;">
  <li class="tab_cont">
    <a href="/test" class="tab_cont_link">Test</a>
    <a>
      <desc>Testing</desc>
    </a>
  </li>
   <li class="tab_cont">
    <a href="/test" class="tab_cont_link">Test</a>
    <a>
      <desc>Testing</desc>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul class="tab_conts" id="new" style="display: none;">
 <li class="tab_cont">
    <a href="/test" class="tab_cont_link">Test</a>
    <a>
      <desc>Testing</desc>
    </a>
  </li>
   <li class="tab_cont">
    <a href="/test" class="tab_cont_link">Test</a>
    <a>
      <desc>Testing</desc>
    </a>
  </li>
   <li class="tab_cont">
    <a href="/test" class="tab_cont_link">Test</a>
    <a>
      <desc>Testing</desc>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
$(document).on("ready int:ready", function() {
var e = $(".tab_name"),
  t = $(".tab_conts").hide();
e.prependTo(".tabs-cn"), e.click(function(n) {
  n.preventDefault();
  var i = $(this),
    r = e.index(i);
  e.removeClass("tab_name-active"), i.addClass("tab_name-active"), t.hide().eq(r).show()
}), e.first().click() })
```

Comment: You should be able to do what you're after with almost entirely CSS, then just move the `selected` tag around using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab_name').on('click',function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.tab_conts').css({'display':'none'});
        $(href).css({'display':'block'})
    });
});`

PS. make sure you include jquery in your head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the `href` var? You seem to be assigning a (url) string to it, then trying to use it as a JQuery selector?? (which defiantly shouldn't actually select anything) I think you may have messed something up in that answer.

Comment: Check out the Jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/6oq3t9ev/1/), he uses an 'href' to define what tab should be active. That's why I'm using it as a selector.